# Stove-side table material

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-counters, countertops

My apartment has a small gas stove, and I'd like to build a small table next to it to act as additional counter-space (as there's currently no counter-space immediately next to the stove) and also as storage.  As the stove is a gas stove, with actual flames (and it's completely non-electric, so the pilot lights are on at all times), I figure that I probably should use some sort of flame-safe material for the top of the table.  Ideally, it would also be a material that'd be easy to clean, as the area around the stove tends to get greasy from splatters and greasy air (there's no hood or vent).  Unfortunately, since it's a small table (the top will be ~18"x28"), I don't see a slab of stone being a very viable option.  What's the recommended material for this sort of application?

Comment: I don't know where you are, but you might find that a trip to a few stone yards can yield something surprisingly cheap. They've got scraps aplenty. (Though when it comes to pricing it, they'll call it "inventory"; that's when the negotiation begins.)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate has a very good point here. I've purchased "scraps" of granite and marble for a number of small projects at prices that I found very reasonable.